# Swift - how to fix when adding a Physics Body removes sprite node from scene

Tags: swift, physics

I'm fairly new to programming and can't seem to figure out this Physics World issue. When I add a physics body to my sprite node, i can no longer see the sprite node in the scene.

Code:

```
func createBird() {

    let randomSpawn = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    if randomSpawn == 1 {
    let newX = Int(-20)
    let newY = Int(arc4random_uniform(500) + 300)
    var p = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
    var destination = CGPoint(x:Int(self.frame.width+21), y:newY)

    var moverSpeed = Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 3)

   let birdRight = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "bird-right1")
    birdRight.xScale = 0.6
    birdRight.yScale = 0.6
    birdRight.position = p
    birdRight.zPosition = 2

    //birdRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: birdRight.size)
    birdRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    birdRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = birdCategory
    birdRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory
    birdRight.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    let birdMoveRight = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right1"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right4"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right5"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right6"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right7"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right8"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right9"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-right10")
        ], timePerFrame: 0.05)

   let foreverAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(birdMoveRight)

    birdRight.runAction(foreverAction)

    let duration = NSTimeInterval(moverSpeed)

    let action = SKAction.moveTo(destination, duration: duration)

    birdRight.runAction(action)

    addChild(birdRight)


    }

    else {

        let newX = Int(self.frame.width+20)
        let newY = Int(arc4random_uniform(500) + 300)
        var p = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
        var destination = CGPoint(x:-21, y:newY)

        var moverSpeed = Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 3)

        let birdLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bird-left1")
        birdLeft.xScale = 0.6
        birdLeft.yScale = 0.6
        birdLeft.position = p
        birdLeft.zPosition = 2

        let birdMoveLeft = SKAction.animateWithTextures([
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left1"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left2"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left3"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left4"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left5"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left6"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left7"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left8"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left9"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-left10")
            ], timePerFrame: 0.05)

        birdLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: birdLeft.size)
        birdLeft.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        birdLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = birdCategory
        birdLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory
        birdLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        let foreverAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(birdMoveLeft)

        birdLeft.runAction(foreverAction)

        let duration = NSTimeInterval(moverSpeed)

        let action = SKAction.moveTo(destination, duration: duration)

        birdLeft.runAction(action)
        addChild(birdLeft)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is affected by gravity and get dragged all the way down before you even see the object on your screen?
Try this:

```
  birdRight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```